# C++ library output

Tags: c++

I am writing a library which is based on `c` socket. Everything is wrapped into `C++` classes. It currently output a lot of data on the standard output. 
I do not think (I suppose) that it is a good way to build a library, I should leave this task to the user of the library.

I have some ideas to tell the user that an operation failed or succeeded but I do not know which one to consider:

- Return `c-like` error codes?
- Throw exceptions?

The library can also displays warning messages. Should I used the standard output or the standard error output for this task?

Comment: Your proposed solution are language depended: first for [tag:c], second for [tag:c++]. So the second cannot be applied if you are going to you [tag:c]

Comment: About warning message, it is in you hands: I used to use `stderr`

Comment: This is too broad.  *Personally*, I would provide a way for the user of your library to steer warning messages - probably by providing a function which takes a string to sends it somewhere.  I would default to writing to stderr.

Comment: @Papipone it is up to decide, just pick one and stick with it. there are numerous pros and cons that depend on the environment e.g. is it in an embedded environment, desktop etc. a library used in a desktop environment may need to present errors in a window etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to stack at `printf debugging` swamp. It is definitely an indication or absent / poor error handling. If you are writing in C++ then you should use exceptions. Note that C-style error codes in C++ can not be used is some cases such as constructor / destructors and attempts to workaround (such as making objects with trivial constructors / destructors but with mandatory methods like `Init`/`Uninit`) typically lead to even uglier code.

Comment: Wrapping error return codes of  Linux syscalls in a exception class should be a smarter idea?

Comment: Probably yes. However simply using exceptions to throw C error codes around (or just throwing raw error codes) is also not very good. You probably need to define an exception class (deriving from `std::exception`) for each error domain in your library. For example if it takes an url as an input and tries to connect it then you would probably need to throw something like `NameResolutionException` when DNS resolving fails and `IoException` when data transfer fails. Both of them can probably carry an error code and some other info but the type of exception itself is a valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use a library in production code, it's normally unacceptable for it to produce error messages, certainly on stdout but also on stderr. So the choice is error codes or exceptions. If you provide a C++ only interface, you can use exceptions, if C, you must return error codes.

However a socket library is likely to report errors when the hardware is experiencing problems. This is often regarded by higher level code as normal flow control. Everyone knows that a url might not actually link, including the user. So error codes rather than exceptions are indicated here, though ultimately it's a judgement call.

Answer (score -1):

A library should not output many things : you do not know how your library will be used (CLI, batch processing, GUI, ...).

For the warning messages use stderr.

c-like error code are a bad idea. Either use functional like `option` object (cf `std::optional`) or use exception.

If you're building a C++ wrapper around C library I recommend you to watch [this video from the 2014 CPPCON about how to call C code from C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZO0V4Prefc)